# ActionScript 3 Singleton instantiation - advice

Tags: actionscript-3, singleton, instantiation

I have an AS3 Singleton:

```
package 
    {
        public class Singleton
        {
            public function Singleton(enforcer:SingletonEnforcer):void
            {
                if(!enforcer){throw new Error("Only one instance of Singleton Class allowed.");}
            }

            private static var _instance:Singleton;
            public static function getInstance():Singleton
            {
                if(!Singleton._instance)
                {
                    Singleton._instance=new Singleton(new SingletonEnforcer());
                }
                return Singleton._instance;
            }
        }
    }
class SingletonEnforcer{}
```

Consider `prop` and `func()` to be a property and method respectively of the Singleton class.

How should I access them?

1. Make them static and use this:

```
Singleton.getInstance();
Singleton.prop;
Singleton.func();
```

2. Not make them static and use this:

```
Singleton.getInstance().prop;
Singleton.getInstance().func();
```

Does it matter, or is it just visual prefference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *reason* to use a singleton instance is so that you can have class members used in a (relatively) static way.

<sub>I won't get into the arguments over whether or not to use a singleton here, there's a very long debate over whether it's a good pattern or not.</sub>

Typically, when singletons are used, you store access to them in a local variable and use them like any other class instance. The primary difference, is instead of using:

```
foo = new Foo();
```

You use:

```
foo = Foo.instance;
//Actionscript supports properties which makes this a self-initializing call
-or-
foo = Foo.getInstance();
```

Followed by

```
foo.bar();
foo.baz();
foo.fizz = 'buzz';
```

This doesn't mean that `Foo` can't have static members of the class, but the rules for adding static members on a Singleton are the same for adding static members to *any other* class. If the function belongs to the instance, it should be used on the instance, if it belongs to the class, it should be static.

Comment: You can also use `Foo.getInstance().bar()` rather than creating a reference to the singleton. This is probably better if you are only going to use the singleton once in a given class, because it removes the worry of cleaning up additional references at some future point.

Comment: I see, so you are saying, I should use `foo=new Foo();` as I would with any other class, correct?

Comment: shanethehat: I use it for DB access. I just want to have `Foo.getInstance().getAllPersons();` etc. (synchronously)

Comment: @shanethehat, I use `Foo.getInstance().bar()` in places where i would use `(new Foo()).bar()` if I were *not* using a singleton. for consistency sake, I prefer to use `foo = Foo.getInstance()` especially in case I want to change to using a different object (or possibly a subclass). If you assign to a local variable, you only have to change one instance of a class name, versus having to change the call *everywehre*.

Comment: @zzzzBov - Absolutely, and I do it like you say 9 times of 10. I just wanted to make clear that the alternative does work.